# Ignore Undefined values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, undefined

I have a huge xml data which has to be parsed. There are few undefined values. As a result i am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined` error. Is there any way to handle these undefined values and continue with execution of program. Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your code, otherwise it's hard to say anything.

Comment: Would be beneficial to show your parse and your data or state which parser you are using?

Comment: before calling 'childNodes' check whether  it is present or not using hasOwnProperty attribute.

Comment: Please show us some actual XML and code. This question is far too vague.

Comment: @priya_singh Calling `.hasOwnProperty` on `undefined` will cause the same error.

Comment: @JLRishe No. I have used it.

Comment: @priya_singh http://jsfiddle.net/afzq55jp/

Comment: @JLRishe Not like this. If you have object type structure and you know some data might not be present at that time only hasOwnProperty  will work.

Comment: @priya_singh The problem he has is that he's getting an `undefined` value, not an object.

Comment: @Barmar  Ya. But as he is having xml data there may be object which is not having childnodes peroperty right??

Comment: @priya_singh No, there's an earlier step where he's getting `undefined` instead of a node. It's not an object without a property, it's a non-object.

Comment: @Barmar Ok. May be you are right. As i don't know his code

Comment: @priya_singh All XML DOM nodes have a `childNodes` property. It's clear from the question that OP is trying to access `.childNodes` on an `undefined` value (as I have already said).

Comment: @JLRishe Yes. you are right. first check this example https://www.w3schools.com/xml/prop_document_childnodes.asp and in this if he check xml.hasOwnProperty("responseXML") then he will not get undefined error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WIthout source, it's hard to tell but generally where your parser make something like `Value = parsedValue` (assigns the parsed value to something like an array, list, whatever) you can use `Value = parsedValue || defaulValue`.

This is JS shortcut how to go around undefined and null values. The default value can be as simple as `""` or `0`.

If your problem is that object misses some property that parser thought it has assigned then its time for another shortcut:

```
Value = (myObject && myObject.myProperty && myObject.myProperty.itsProperty) ? myObject.myProperty.itsProperty : undefined;
```

Comment: That will prevent this error, but probably cause a new error when he tries to loop through `Value.childNodes`.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting the `childNodes`, test if your value is defined.

```
if (something) {
    var children = something.childNodes;
    // process children
}
```